# Why some brush types in the Create New Brush dialog are disabled?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I created a new Pattern Brush to test a new symbol I designed, and then decided to create a new Scatter Brush instead. But when I click the New Brush button in the Brushes palette, now the dialog box has 2 brushes greyed out (the Scatter Brush and Art Brush). Previously all of them were available. What would cause that to happen? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scatter brush' and Art brush' have to be made *out of* created "artwork" (some object(s) on your artboard).

When you go to New Brush, if making a Scatter or Art brush, have the objects you want to turn into a brush selected

---

You can also just Select the artwork (to turn into a brush) and just Drag it into your brushes and it will pop up asking you what kind of brush you are making.
(Scatter, Art or Pattern)